# Does PHP only work with Apache, or can I make it work with my own c ++ server?

Tags: php, c++, interaction

Does PHP only work with Apache, or can I make it work with my own c ++ server?

For example, can I send a request from my c ++ program to php, so that php runs "file.php" and then returns the result to my c ++ program?

Comment: Yes you can, read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: This is the reverse of what you're asking... but might give you some ideas... https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/executing-c-code-from-within-php-code-558879/

Comment: See also: PHP-FPM (PHP as a FastCGI module) and PHP in a CGI environment. mod_php is just one deployment option.

Comment: PHP can be executed command line `php -r "echo 'PHP did this';"` so apache isn't needed. Probably looking for something like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is an interpreted language. Besides using it through [Apache mod_php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php), it supports CGI and FastCGI calls setup. So you can either:

1. call it's [interpreter in CGI mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php) to execute a PHP script file; or
2. run [php-fpm server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) in the background then call it to run any PHP file with the FastCGI protocol.

I believe multiple libraries in C++ are there for making either or both [CGI](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=cgi&type=Repositories) and [FastCGI](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=fastcgi&type=Repositories) calls. For example, [darrengarvey/cgi](https://github.com/darrengarvey/cgi) can do both.

#### CGI Without a Library

If you go for the CGI path, you can even do it without a library. With php-cgi properly installed, you can make a regular CGI call like this:

```
echo "test=1" | \
REQUEST_METHOD=POST \
CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded \
CONTENT_LENGTH=6 \
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1 \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/full/path/to/file.php \
REDIRECT_STATUS=true \
REQUEST_URI=/hello/world \
php-cgi
```

As you can see, a CGI call is a regular system call with some predefined environment variables (a.k.a. [Request Meta-Variables](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1)). The HTTP request body is supplied to STDIN. The complete HTTP response (headers included) will be sent through STDOUT.

#### Difference between CGI and FastCGI

Since every CGI call will be a system call, it take time to load PHP libraries / modules into memory everytime you call. [FastCGI](http://www.mit.edu/%7Eyandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html) specified a way to send/receive STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR over line protocol. php-fpm would load up memory and pool connections to make the call faster. Hence the name **Fast**CGI.

Comment: I've reached my question limit, so I hope it's ok with one following question here: 

What is the difference if my c program involves php through system call / command line instead of CGI? Doesn't CGI have to do the same thing somewhere in the process?

Comment: A CGI call is a regular system call / command line call. You'd just call the CGI executor (e.g. php-cgi) then supply all the required data through environment variable (i.e. in bash, `export VARNAME=value`) and STDIN. But you need to have the correct set of environment variable to make things work for standard CGI program. So there is basically no difference between the two.

Comment: In your bash / shell environment, you can make a CGI call like this: `echo "test=1" | REQUEST_METHOD=POST CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded CONTENT_LENGTH=6 GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1 SCRIPT_FILENAME=/full/path/to/file.php REDIRECT_STATUS=true REQUEST_URI=/hello/world php-cgi`. The php-cgi command will interpret the PHP file. And the PHP file will treat this as a regular POST request. You'd get the resulting HTTP response (headers included) from STDOUT.